# Why does a property in an object need to be set and not private set when using newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json, class, json.net, set, private

I recenlty made a register and came upon a problem whereby this line below wouldnt work unless my properties in my person object were set and not private set

```
AllPeopleAdded.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(File.ReadAllText(jsonfilePath)));
```

When I say doesnt work I mean that the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject returns null values to my the list.

The person class has 2 properties

```
        public string mFirstName {get;set; }
        public string mLastName {get;set; }
```

Is there a reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can still make your property private but you need to add attributes. This will be working properly

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string mFirstName { get; private set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string mLastName { get; private set; }
}
```

even this will be working, but it doesn't make much use

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty]
    private string mFirstName;
    [JsonProperty]
    private string mLastName;

}
```